# Convert String to Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have a little problem with creating a new function from a string.
The example: I have a div, and some buttons. One of the buttons just make my div animating, nothing else. But the other button make the div animating and after the animation is complete, call a new function.

I have to handle the new, following function as a variable, because there will be a lot of function I have to call after the div animated.

Here is an example I made: http://jsfiddle.net/AmVSq/3/. I hope you can understand my problem.

I found the `new Function();` in JavaScript but it just left me in doubt and the JS console did not log anything.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thank you so much..

Comment: Don't mix JavaScript and HTML. You're already using jQuery, bind events using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) or [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are "first class" objects. This means you can assign them to variables and pass them to other functions as parameters.

There is no need to create a function from a string when you can pass the function name itself, like so:

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="close_div( alert_me );">Close Div then do something</a></div>
```

and the script:

```
function close_div( next_function ) {
    $('#wrap').animate({ 'height': '-=100px' }, 300, function() {
        if ( next_function ) {
            // do the following function
            next_function();
        }
    });
}
```

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/AmVSq/5/)

In fact, for your purposes, you can simply pass `next_function` right along to the `animate` function, like this:

```
function close_div( next_function ) {
    $('#wrap').animate({ 'height': '-=100px' }, 300, next_function);
}
```

There's no need to check if `next_function` is `undefined`, because `.animate` will do that for you.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I handle the following as a string (with putting it between apostrophes) and not as a real function. Thank you very much, it works.

Comment: No problem @b_benjamin. See my edit for how to shorten your code even further.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like more accurate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing wrong is using `new Function` at all. The correct way is to just pass the function, which are objects like anything else in JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/AmVSq/6/

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="close_div();">Close Div</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="close_div(alert_me);">Close Div then do something</a></div>
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="close_div(confirm_me);">Close Div then do another thing</a></div>
<div id="wrap"></div>​
```

```
function close_div( next_function ) {
    $('#wrap').animate({ 'height': '-=100px' }, 300, function() {
        if(next_function) {
            next_function();
        }
    });
}

function alert_me() {
    alert( 'The animation is complete' );
}

function confirm_me() {
    confirm('Are you sure?');
}
```

Or, more concisely, `$('#wrap').animate({height: '-100px'}, 300, next_function);`.

Answer (score 1):

The chrome console displays the result properly:

```
> f = new Function("alert('hello');");
function anonymous() {
  alert('hello');
}
> f(); //executes it.
```

But using string to create function, or passing strings to functions to execute it is really bad practice.

```
function test(callback) {
    callback();
}

test(function() { alert("hello"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make the function into a string, you can pass functions as arguments to other functions in Javascript.

For example:

```
function get_message1() {
    return "hello world";
}

function get_message2() {
    return "yay for first-class functions";
}

function print_message(message_func) {
    console.log(message_func())
}

print_message(get_message1);
print_message(get_message2);
```

Comment: I understand this is kinda like @jackwanders wrote down in the following reply but it just does not work for me. I double-checked everything.